# Connect to MariaDB through SSH fails with error 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

Tags: centos, mysql, mariadb, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a remote MariaDB server through SSH using Navicat Premium from Windows but all the time I can't and get this error:

> 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

I have read and follow many guides on Internet so I get lost at this point and don't know what else to do. This is what I have done:

At server side (remote host with CentOS 6.6 and mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.44-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1):

- `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf` setup this parameters:

  ```
  [mysqld]
  #skip-networking

  #tried with this
  bind-address = 0.0.0.0

  #tried with this
  bind-address = 127.0.0.1

  #tried with this
  bind-address = localhost
  ```

  **RESULT:** No success, same error and can't connect
- `/etc/hosts.allow` set this parameters:

  ```
  # tried with this
  #ALL:ALL
  # tried with this
  ALL:PARANOID
  # tried with this
  ALL:MY_IP_ADDR
  ```

  **RESULT:** No success, same error and can't connect
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` setup parameters for allow TCP forwarding:

  AllowTcpForwarding yes

  **RESULT:** No success, same error and can't connect

Server has IPTABLES enabled but port 3306 is open:

```
#MySQL/MariaDB
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

This is how the configuration looks like on Navicat:

[image]
[image]

Can any give me a hand on this? I have spent hours on this without success

Comment: `ssh -L 3306:mysqlServer.example.com:3306 user@mysqlServer.example.com` and `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` would be the normal way of doing this. What are you trying to accomplish by connecting through an SSH tunnel?

Comment: @lVlint67 Because server is not open and I can't access directly to port 3306 then I need to connect through a tunnel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you tried 127.0.0.1 as the hostname on the "General" Tab of your application?**

It's hard to tell exactly what this application is trying to do (remote/local/dynamic tunnel)

---

I have to do something similar to get to a remote Oracle Database we use... I have the luxury of having access to either a linux workstation or cygwin.

I am not familiar with the software you are using... But when I have to get into our database from *other* machines I use PuTTY. A google search (PuTTY Local ssh tunnel) will provide results for instructions:
http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/

Set the local port to whatever you want (I would just use 3306 for clarity) and the destination as yoursever:3306. Then use whatever SQL client you want to connect to 127.0.0.1:3306.

### /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bind_addess = 127.0.0.1
```

---

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
#should be the only firewall statement you need assuming ssh is open..
```

Comment: Ok, you have saved my day, setting DB IP to `127.0.0.1` fix the issue, many thanks